# It is a Telegram bot API bug?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, php-telegram-bot

Working with the bots API.

When I try to use /sendmessage function:

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

if the text var contains " H" (blank space + H), the message is not sent. Is a bug?

For example, messages with text similar to this not sent: "My name is Julia Hi" or "I am testing HTML tags msg"

https://api.telegram.org/**botAPI**/sendmessage?chat_id=**XXXXXX**&parse_mode=HTML&text=**My name is Julia Hi**

```
$path = "https://api.telegram.org/YOURBOTAPI";

file_get_contents($path."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$A_CHATID."&text=My name is Julia Hi");
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Make sure you use `urlencode()` or `http_build_query()` when creating URL query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I think is a Telegram API BUG, however I solved it encoding the text param as sugested @Barmar

```
$text = urlencode('My name is Julia Hi')
$path = "https://api.telegram.org/YOURBOTAPI";
file_get_contents($path."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$A_CHATID."&text=".$text);
```